# What is Web Service Definition Language

Tags: wsdl, soa

What does the article below mean by Web Service Definition Language?

> Service interfaces are frequently defined using Web Service Definition
> Language (WSDL) which is a standard tag structure based on xml
> (extensible markup language).
> Source: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/soa

I am confused by the word "interface". Interface makes me think it's front end, but that cannot be right.

Is this right? For example, if I build a website application, a directory would include a file (example.xml) which would be written in Web Service Definition Language. The examle.xml file would be used by the computer to request and interoperate data.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read about the meaning of an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)). In plain words, to interface with something means to interact, or connect, or communicate with something. In the world of web services this means connecting to or communicating with a web service.

So from that point of view, the service has an interface (often the word contract is also used).

To know the specifics of how exactly this interface works it needs to be described to you, i.e. what are the details to connect and interact/communicate. WSDLs are a way to define this, with the advantage of allowing it to be used by tools to generate the necessary code to interact with the web service.

[WSDLs are usually used with SOAP web services.](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b)